# How do I observe a value change in a GetxController class and trigger navigation in the statelessWidget class using GetX in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Im in a scenario that I need to receive data on a async task, then decide wether to navigate to the next page or not based on the replying.

But as far as I know, the state management in GetX support widget rebuild when value change in GetxController using `.obs` and `obx()`.

What should I do to observe the value change then trigger the navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out a simple `ever<T>` method inherited from the `GetxController` class do the trick.

And it turns out that you shouldn't hybrid `provider`, `get_it` and `get_x` all together. Bring lots of unnecessary pain which will cause some of the feature in `get_x` not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can us navigation in your async method or even in your method on complete call.

Suppose you call your async method and use dot then method you can put your response value in a varibale and can put conditions on it either it should navigate or not.

```
Future<int> getData()async{
print('Asynce Method');
return 1;
}
getData().then((result){
print(result);
if(result == 1){
//       Navigate here
}
else{
//       Don't Navigate
}
});
```

Comment: I use ````ever<T>```` method to achieve at the end. But thanks for the sharing.